# ISO-8859-6 to UTF-8

Tags: c#, encoding, arabic

How do I convert ISO-8859-6 to Arabic?

I have some encoded characters, e.g. `ÇÎÊÈÇÑ`. This is nothing but “Test” in English and `اختبار` in Arabic.

I want these characters as an input and Arabic as an output. To test further in Notepad++, try the following steps to get a better idea.

1. Create New file and paste `ÇÎÊÈÇÑ` in it.
2. Go to encoding menu navigation -> Character Set -> Arabic -> ISO-8859-6/Windows-1256

It shows Arabic characters, which is nothing but “test” (`Google Translator`).
Actually, I want to replicate the reverse process, however I am unable to do same process L.
This is the code I'm trying:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ÇÎÊÈÇÑ");
System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_6 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-6");
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, iso_8859_6, utf8Bytes);
string unicodeconverted = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(isoBytes);
//string uf8converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(isoBytes);
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: @Mat: [This would have added it.](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/657316) Could you merge the edits, please? Is that possible? 

Comment: @qwzjk: there's no "merge edit" feature. Not sure why your edit got rejected - it was possibly submitted at the same time mine was... applied your changes to the question.

Comment: `“ÇÎÊÈÇÑ”` is certainly **not** `Test` and `اختبار` in UTF-8, as the `.cs` file is normally encoded as `UTF-8`.

Comment: `Unicode` is Microsoft speak for `UTF-16` and not `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 2):

Quick conversion of a windows-1256 file to utf8:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"));  
File.WriteAllText(path, data, Encoding.UTF8);
```