# Not able to see Arabic characters after converting the file from ISO 8859-6 to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

In my application, I am reading a file having some Arabic characters (encoding is `ISO 8859-6`) and I am converting it to `UTF-8` encoding and writing back in a new file using `BufferedWriter`. However, in my newly generated file, I am unable to see the Arabic characters, instead few question marks are coming.

Snippet from my original File

```
Sample Data//لمند
Another line,
One more line/لمند
```

Snippet from the generated file

```
 Sample Data//????
 Another line,
 One more line/????
```

I am using below method for conversion:

```
private String convertCharSet(String data, String sourceCharacterCode, String destinationCharacterCode) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
        Charset charsetSource = Charset.forName(sourceCharacterCode);
        Charset charsetDestination = Charset.forName(destinationCharacterCode);
        ByteBuffer inputByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.getBytes(sourceCharacterCode));
        CharBuffer charBuffer = charsetSource.decode(inputByteBuffer);
        ByteBuffer outputByteBuffer = charsetDestination.encode(charBuffer);
        return new String(outputByteBuffer.array(), destinationCharacterCode);
}
```

I am using below method for writing into file

```
public static void writeToFile(String filePath, String data) throws IOException
{
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try
    {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePath)));
        out.write(data);
        out.flush();
    }
    finally
    {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**Observations**

1. In `notepad++`, I opened the file in `ISO 8859-6` format and I could
   see the Arabic characters. I converted it to `UTF-8` using `Convert to UTF-8` option and there I could see the Arabic characters after conversion.
2. I have debugged my program in `eclipse`, there before conversion I could see the Arabic characters and after conversion to `UTF-8` also I could see the Arabic characters. But once the contents are written into the file, I am getting those `?` marks instead of Arabic characters.

**Note**

- In eclipse, I am using `-Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-6` as virtual
  argument.
- I have seen [ISO-8859-6 to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448060/iso-8859-6-to-utf-8), but that does not
  resolve my problem.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java (as opposed to other languages) text, `String/Char/Reader/Writer` is Unicode, being able to combine all scripts.

So the conversion must take place not between Strings, but between String and binary data, `byte[]/InputStream/OutputStream`.

```
Path sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/data/arab.txt");
byte[] sourceData = Files.readAllBytes(sourcePath);

String s = new String(sourceData, "ISO-8859-6");

byte[] targetData = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
Files.write(targetData, targetPath, StandardOpenOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

As you see, it is conceptual easy in java - once one knows.

FileWriter/FileReader are old utility classes, that use the default platform encoding. Not portable. Only for local files.

---

***In java 1.6 (without Exception handling):***

```
File sourceFile = ...
File targetFile = ...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        new FileInputStream(sourceFile), "ISO-8859-6"));
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOuputStream(targetFile), "UTF-8"));
for (;;) {
    String line = in.readLine();
    if (line == null) {
        break;
    }
    out.write(line);
    out.write("\r\n"); // Windows CR+LF.
}
out.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. But I have a constraint to use Java 1.6. Is there any way to achieve the same with 1.6?

Comment: I followed your BufferedReader. Advantage: very large files are read and written in chunks, by line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. +1 for such a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

You `writeToFile` method is broken. You are opening an imlicit `Writer` without specifying the encoding. Standard platform encoding will be used. You files will be broken. Use a `Writer` which accepts one encoding.